# JavaScript OAuth Popup window handler code

Tags: javascript, oauth, popup

I'm using oAuth to login or sign up using gmail account and decided to use popup window to do it. I found a snippet [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/oauth-popup-window/) which describes the process. But I can't understand how I'll be able to get the values or code if the user logged in with his email.

I can open the modal by this:

```
//Authorization popup window code
$.oauthpopup = function(options)
{
    options.windowName = options.windowName ||  'ConnectWithOAuth'; // should not include space for IE
    options.windowOptions = options.windowOptions || 'location=0,status=0,width=800,height=400';
    options.callback = options.callback || function(){ window.location.reload(); };
    var that = this;
    log(options.path);
    that._oauthWindow = window.open(options.path, options.windowName, options.windowOptions);
    that._oauthInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
        if (that._oauthWindow.closed) {
            window.clearInterval(that._oauthInterval);
            options.callback();
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

And use that as follows:

```
$.oauthpopup({
    path: urltoopen,
    callback: function()
    {
        log('callback');
        //do callback stuff
    }
});
```

But now, I'm wondering how to auto close the popup and pass parameters from popup window to the main window.

Comment: That's what callback function is for, isn't it?

Comment: @dhiraj how to use it in this context?